# No main manifest attribute, in executable jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller, manifest

while running my jar I receive the below error

> No main manifest attribute, in jar

I have followed some of the solutions provided here but it did not solve the

problem, I have tried to delete the manifest folder and file and rebuild the

artifacts to create a new jar, change my build section in pom file and also

checked to see if the main class path is in the manifest file, It all seems

to be okie

I am adding here my build section in the POM file and the manifest file

I will appreciate your help

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxApplication
```

Comment: try `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` and check